# Accessing my Protege OWL Ontology using Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, owl, ontology, protege

I've just built a new OWL ontology in protege (classes, properties and individuals). 
My problem is: How can I access (query) the individuals to use it in a program written in Java under Eclipse.

I've tried the following:

1. Generate the ontology java code and try to load it using Jena in
   Eclipse but that requires programming using jena and Im not sure if
   I need this.
2. Add protege plugin in Eclipse and try to access the OWL file to read
   from the file but that also didn't work.

Thus what is the proper method for accessing (Querying) the OWL individuals from protege  in a Java program written under Eclipse.

Comment: As Michael says below, you will have to use one library or another, so some complication is to be expected. But any of the libraries mentioned has decent documentation, so it's not that hard. Thwyvare all independent of the actual IDE, you can use Eclipse or IntelliJ or Netbeans with the same effort.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a Java library for RDF.  You mention Jena, but there's also [Sesame](http://openrdf.org).  Or if you want something OWL specific, you could try the [OWLAPI](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/).

There's nothing fancy you need to do to use your ontology in an application.  Any of the aforementioned libraries can read it in, it's just RDF after all, and provide programmatic access directly such as iterating over the triples, or via queries or other lookup mechanisms.

All three libraries have good documentation to get you started on how you'd read in and use your ontology.  You might stick with the OWLAPI if you want to use a reasoner, or want to do OWL-specific manipulations of the data.